# Can a Goddess give birth to an ugly child?

Tags: goddess

Goddesses are all powerful, all knowing, all present. So my question is can a Goddess give birth to an ugly child? (Ugly child means a child with disgusting features like face with pimples, protruding eyes,misplaced eyes, defective ears etc...)

Comment: Which Goddess gave birth to such a child? I'm just curious to know.

Comment: She gave birth to an ugly child but the child was taken away... She was a Goddess...you can assume any Goddess... She was a mother.